# Layover in Shenzhen and Guangzhou

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, china, vietnamese-citizens

I just booked a return ticket from Melbourne to Hanoi with a 22-hour layover (overnight) in Shenzhen and a 5-hour layover in Guangzhou on the return leg. I was just wondering if I need to apply for a transit visa and how much will it cost? I've read $30 in one place and ~$100 in others. Where do I apply (I've checked and the Consulate in Melbourne do not accept visa application and it has to go through a commercial service, visaforchina.org). I hold a Vietnamese passport. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Transit without visa (TWOV) is **not** possible at Fuzhou
>      (FOC), Mudanjiang (MDG), **Shenzhen (SZX)** and Yanji (YNJ).

So yes, you absolutely need a transit visa

Comment: Hi! Thank you, I've read that but no info on Chinese gov website so I've planned to apply already. I understand that the visa requirement also applies to cases when travellers would not leave the sterile area? Thanks!

Comment: @Jill Shenzhen doesn't have a transit corridor in the first place - everyone has to clear immigration

Comment: Why the downvotes? 144-hour "transit" is only in force at Shanghai, Nanjing and Hangzhou at the moment, although it will be introduced in Guangdong